# How to figure out what windows forms modules to import in ironpython?

Tags: python, ironpython, windowsformsintegration

I am trying to copy some of the code from the example included [in this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize.aspx) and modify it to run on iron python [using some help from these tutorials](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/winforms/). But I'm stuck as when stepping outside the tutorials, I don't know what modules I need to be importing.

At the moment I have the following code

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")

from System.Windows.Forms import Application, Form, Button, Label, DockStyle, AnchorStyles, Panel, Screen, FlowLayoutPanel

class OKWindow(Form):
   def __init__(self,InfoTXT):
      newlines = 0
      screenSize = Screen.GetWorkingArea(self)
      STRwidth = 200
      STRheight = 30
      FORMheight = 160 
      FORMwidth = 300
      self.Text = 'Information'
      self.Height = FORMheight
      self.Width = FORMwidth


      self.flowPanel = FlowLayoutPanel()
      #self.flowPanel.AutoSize = true
      #self.flowPanel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
      self.Controls.Add(flowPanel)

      label = Label()
      label.Text = InfoTXT
      label.Top = 30
      label.Left = 50
      label.Height = STRheight
      label.Width = STRwidth

      button = Button()
      button.Text = "OK"
      button.Width = 100
      button.Top = FORMheight - 80
      button.Left = (FORMwidth / 2) - 50
      print button.Anchor
      button.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom

      button.Click += self.buttonPressed

      self.Controls.Add(label)
      self.Controls.Add(button)

   def buttonPressed(self, sender, args):
      Application.Exit()

def information(Message):
   Application.EnableVisualStyles()
   form = OKWindow(Message)
   Application.Run(form)
```

(Note: The code is not exact as it's currently running within OCTGN's iron python scripting engine. I call the information() function from elsewhere with some text such as `information('Important Announcement')`.)

So the code aborts as soon as I try to execute this `self.flowPanel = FlowLayoutPanel()`. If I comment out the flowPanel lines, the windows form appears normally.

So it seems to me that I haven't imported the module that is needed properly. Unfortunately I have no idea what to load. I tried loading whatever I thought would be the right one, but none seem to work for me.

How can I figure out what module to import from `System.Windows.Forms` in order to create a FlowLayoutPanel in my code? And in general how does one figure out what to import in order to get the relevant functionality?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I managed to find the answer to this: It seems the module name to import was after all `FlowLayoutPanel` but my code was failing bbecause I prepended the variable with `self.` due to copypasta >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be that it's whatever is after the third dot '.' in System.Windows.Forms

So to use System.Windows.Forms.Form, you need to import Form.

Answer (score 1):

All answers wrong.
   AutoSizeMode is missing in the import, then the code works

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")



from System.Windows.Forms import Application, Form, Button, Label, DockStyle, AnchorStyles, Panel, Screen, FlowLayoutPanel,AutoSizeMode

#from System.Windows.Forms import *



class OKWindow(Form):
    def __init__(self,InfoTXT):
        newlines = 0
        screenSize = Screen.GetWorkingArea(self)
        STRwidth = 200
        STRheight = 30
        FORMheight = 160 
        FORMwidth = 300
        self.Text = 'Information'
        self.Height = FORMheight
        self.Width = FORMwidth


        flowPanel = FlowLayoutPanel()
        flowPanel.AutoSize = True
        flowPanel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink

        print(AutoSizeMode)
        self.Controls.Add(flowPanel)

        label = Label()
        label.Text = InfoTXT
        label.Top = 30
        label.Left = 50
        label.Height = STRheight
        label.Width = STRwidth

        button = Button()
        button.Text = "OK"
        button.Width = 100
        button.Top = FORMheight - 80
        button.Left = (FORMwidth / 2) - 50
        #print( button.Anchor)
        button.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom

        button.Click += self.buttonPressed

        self.Controls.Add(label)
        self.Controls.Add(button)

    def buttonPressed(self, sender, args):
        Application.Exit()

def information(Message):
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    form = OKWindow(Message)
    Application.Run(form)

information('laber')
```